# Cannot integrate Gallio MBUnit with Team City

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, mbunit, gallio

I have been trying to get my MBUnit tests suite to work on Team City for many days now without any success.

My solution builds no problem. The program is with my tests. After googling for Gallio integration with Team City I tried many ways to make this thing work and I think I am close but need help.

I have included the gallio bin directory to my repository and also on my TC Server.

Here is my build runner set up in Team City :

Build runner : MSBuild
Build file path : Myproject.msbuild
Targets : RebuildSolution  RunTests

Here is Myproject.msbuild file I created and included in the Source control trunk directory :

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<!-- This is needed by MSBuild to locate the Gallio task -->
<UsingTask AssemblyFile="C:\Gallio\bin\Gallio.MSBuildTasks.dll" TaskName="Gallio" />
<!-- Specify the tests assemblies -->
<ItemGroup>
  <TestAssemblies Include="C:\_CBL\CBL\CoderForTraders\Source\trunk\UnitTest\DomainModel.Tests\bin\Debug\CBL.CoderForTraders.DomainModel.Tests.dll" /> 
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="RunTests">
  <Gallio IgnoreFailures="false" Assemblies="@(TestAssemblies)" RunnerExtensions="TeamCityExtension,Gallio.TeamCityIntegration">
   <!-- This tells MSBuild to store the output value of the task's ExitCode property into the project's ExitCode property -->
   <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ExitCode"/>
  </Gallio>
  <Error Text="Tests execution failed" Condition="'$(ExitCode)' != 0" />
</Target>
<Target Name="RebuildSolution">
  <Message Text="Starting to Build"/>
  <MSBuild Projects="CoderForTraders.sln" 
           Properties="Configuration=Debug" 
           Targets="Rebuild" />
</Target>
</Project>
```

Here are the errors displayed by Team City :

error MSB4064: The "Assemblies" parameter is not supported by the "Gallio" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property

error MSB4063: The "Gallio" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Assemblies attribute has been renamed to Files.
Documentation here: http://www.gallio.org/api/html/T_Gallio_MSBuildTasks_Gallio.htm